if $m^x + y(m-1) = m^a+b(m-1)$ and $m,a,b,x,y \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $m>1$ and $ 0 < x \leq m^y$ and $ 0 < a \leq m^b$ then $x =a$ and $y = b$
Let be $m,a,b,x,y \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $m>1$ and $ 0 < y \leq m^x$ and $ 0 < b \leq m^a$
if $m^x + y(m-1) = m^a+b(m-1)$
then $x =a$ and $y = b$
$\bf Attempt:$
Assume $x \not=a$ and $y \not= b$,
Then (without loss of generality)

($x< a$ and $y < b$) or
($x< a$ and $y > b$)

If 1), then
\begin{align*}
x< a \ \  \ \ \ \ &\text{and } \ \ \ y < b\\
\iff m^x < m^a \ \ \ \ &\text{and } \ \ \ y(m-1) < b(m-1)\\
\iff m^x + y(m-1) &< m^a + b(m-1) \ \
\end{align*}
but this is a contraditcion as  $m^x + y(m-1) = m^a+b(m-1)$.
If 2) then:
\begin{align*}
x< a \ \  \ \ \ \ &\text{and } \ \ \ b < y\\
\iff m^x < m^a \ \ \ \ &\text{and } \ \ \ b(m-1) < y(m-1)\\
\iff m^x + y(m-1) &< m^a + b(m-1) \\
\iff m^x - m^a  &< b(m-1) - y(m-1) \\
\iff m^x - m^a  &< (m-1)(b-y) \\
\end{align*}
and here I'm stuck. There are other soluions, but there is only one integer solution, which is when $x = a$ and $y = b$. Do you know any method to prove that or find a contradiction?
also $bm^x < ym^a$ is true, I dont know if I have to use divisor kind of argument or play around with the inequalities. Also I have not used  $ y \leq m^x$ and $ b \leq m^a$ yet.

I'm sorry, you are right. I incorrectly stated the problem. all variables are strictly positive, $m$ is strictly greater than $1$.  I edited the question.

You made a small mistake with your case $2$. With $m^x \lt m^a$ and $b(m - 1) \lt y(m - 1)$, by adding both sides, we instead have
$$m^x + \color{red}{b}(m - 1) \lt m^a + \color{red}{y}(m - 1)$$
i.e., the $b$ and $y$ were switched around. However, I don't see how to proceed from here. Instead, an alternate method to solve your case is to rearrange your equation to get
$$m^x + y(m - 1) = m^a + b(m - 1) \;\to\; (y - b)(m - 1) = m^a - m^x = m^x(m^{a - x} - 1)$$
Since $y \le m^x$ and $b \gt 0$, then $y - b \lt m^x$. Also, $a - x \ge 1$, so $m - 1 \le m^{a - x} - 1$. However, this gives
$$(y - b)(m - 1) \lt m^x(m^{a - x} - 1)$$
contradicting the earlier equation.

Note there's also a somewhat simpler solution. For any positive integer $n \gt m$, let $c \ge 1$ be the largest integer where $m^c \lt n$ (i.e., $c = \lfloor \log_{m}(n - 1)\rfloor$). This also means $n \le m^{c + 1}$ since, otherwise, $n \gt m^{c+1} \;\to\; m^{c+1} \lt n$, so $c + 1$ would be a larger exponent of $m$ with the value being less than $n$, contradicting that $c$ was the largest. Thus, there's a unique integer $c$ where
$$m^c \lt n \le m^{c+1}$$
With your equation, let $n$ be its value. Then $1 \le y \le m^x$ means that
$$m^x + 1(m - 1) = m^x + m - 1 \le n \le m^x + m^x(m - 1) = m^{x+1} \;\to\; m^x \lt n \le m^{x+1}$$
Similarly, we also get
$$m^a \lt n \le m^{a+1}$$
Thus, the first inequalities in this section gives that
$$x = a$$
Finally, this leads to
$$m^x + y(m-1) = m^a+b(m-1) \;\;\to\;\; y(m-1) = b(m-1) \;\;\to\;\; y = b$$

Ok, I follow you, although  where can I find a proof or a book for the first statement about all positive integers $m^c < n \leq m^{c+1}$? Thank you.

@Alejo Regarding stating that all positive integers $n \gt m$ having $m^c \lt n \le m^{c+1}$, I added some additional explanation to my answer.

yes I have already see. Thank you very much!! I'll add your name in my thesis haha. I hope that´s your real name @John Omelian.

@Alejo You're welcome. Note that my real name is as it's spelled in my user name, i.e., John Omielan, not John Omelian as you wrote (FYI, this is a common misspelling I've seen of my surname).

Sorry! My mistake @John Omielan. Your contribution was a piece missing for a greater proof. Thank you again!
